# Do You Watch the 'Unanswered' Page, Home Page, or another Page?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I'm looking for the best way to use Stack Overflow on a day-to-day basis. I know that for a lot of people, the Home page is probably what they see the most. But I'm wondering if it is more useful to watch the Unanswered page, or another page in order to see the most questions?

**If someone already put your answer, please upvote it.**

Answer (score 16):

Questions sorted by Newest page.

Comment: You can usually catch questions first if you watch this page.  I think it is the easiest way to score rep.  Although, questions do tend to pop up on the main page first sometimes.

Comment: Also, I prefer the Questions page to the homepage because it has a little preview of the body.

Answer (score 8):

**Questions/Newest**

Occasionally **Unanswered** traversing from last page to first.

Answer (score 6):

Home page, occasionally Unanswered.

If it was truly unanswered then I might watch it more. I understand what "unanswered" means on SO, but I'd find it more useful to be able to answer questions that actually had no answers.

Comment: Show me a question in the unanswered view more than a day old that has a good answer.  I'm not not saying they don't exist -- just that this 'noise' is extremely low.  If an answer is at all worthwhile it will almost always get at least one upvote and drop the question from the view.

Answer (score 3):

Unanswered            page

Answer (score 2):

Active / Front page

Answer (score 2):

The exact tags I watch have changed over time, but currently I watch https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+or+netbeans+or+eclipse+or+language-agnostic+or+sofaq+or+regex, sorted by activity. Occasionally I'll check the unanswered questions also.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to do this, but have the list of tags loaded from "interesting" tags?

Comment: I don't think it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the Unanswered page, about 3-4 pages back. You can find a number of questions that don't have any answers at all, and those are the ones I like to try and crack.

Answer (score 1):

Unanswered - From the "middle" of the pack. All in the toil of that Necromancer badge.

Comment: I would just go backward through the tag list, that's how I got both of mine.

Comment: Now that sounds a tad noiseless

Comment: Yeah, necro is a fun one.  I've only managed one so far.  Look for old questions with lots of votes and less than 10 answers if you can.  Of course you also need to be able to add something of value to the thread...

Answer (score 0):

On Stack Overflow I watch

- [`tagged/~perl~`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/~perl~)
- [`tagged/algorithm or regex or rosetta-stone or rant or fun`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm%20or%20regex%20or%20rosetta-stone%20or%20rant%20or%20fun)

On Meta

- [newest](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest)
- [active](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active)

Answer (score 0):

Unanswered + my preferred tags, sorted by newest